# Solr - Copy tokenized multi valued field to a string

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a field which is tokenized and multivalued with many values. I want to use these terms as facets. When I try to search by the term I receive an issue where I search for the term "not necessarily" (we see there is a space) and I get the results for the term "not". This leads me to believe that I can not use a tokenized field as a facet field. I tried to copy the values of the field to a text field with a keywordtokenizer. I am told when checking the schema browser: "Sorry, no Term Info available :(" This is after I delete the old index and upload the documents again. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<copyField source="ColonCancerField" dest="cytokineField"/>

<field name="cytokineField" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" type="Cytokine_Pass"/>
<fieldType name="Cytokine_Pass" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

  <field name="ColonCancerField" type="ColonCancer" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
   termPositions="true"
   termVectors="true"
   termOffsets="true"/>
<fieldType name="ColonCancer" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
<analyzer>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"
            minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
            outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"
    />
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
            words="prefLabels_ColonCancer.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<copyField source="content" dest="ColonCancerField"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to add a field (cancerTerms) and add in the terms there. But I am not doing this outside of Solr. I am using the analysis chain and passing it through a ScriptUpdateProcessor. Here I can take the results of the analysis chain
and store the results to the document (as as strField). Then I facet on this field (cancerTerms). This actually gives me the correct results, it does not give me issues with the not and not necessarily or any other similar issue. Also I am not storing the the analysis chain field (I was previously). It makes no sense to store this because it was a copy field (apparently copy fields only copy the source text then pipe it to the analyzer, and cannot be chained). I am only storing the results of the chain (which is useful for faceting).

Here is a simplified view as to what I am doing:

***Content*** [is copied to] -> ***ColonCancerField*** (analysis chain [not stored,
and will produce tokenized strings]) ->***Passed to update-script*** (processed
each token as string) [added to] -> ***CancerTerms*** (strField)

> **id:**   2040ee23-c5dc-459c-969f-2ebf6c728184
>
> **title:**    Immune profile modulation of blood and mucosal eosinophils in nasal polyposis with concomitant asthma.
>
> **content:**  BACKGROUND: Chronic rhinosinusitis with nasal polyps (CRSwNP) is frequently associated with asthma. Mucosal eosinophil (EO)
>   infiltrate has been found to correlate with asthma and disease
>   severity but not necessarily in every patient. Other multifactorial
>   immune processes are required to determine disease endotypes and
>   response to treatment. OBJECTIVE: To evaluate EO immunomodulation for
>   migration and survival in accordance with inflammatory protein
>   profiles and asthmatic status in CRSwNP. METHODS: Ninety-three
>   patients (47 with asthma) with CRSwNP were included. Each patient was
>   staged clinically according to symptom severity and polyp size. Nasal
>   secretions were collected to establish a cytokine profile. The EOs
>   were purified from blood samples and nasal polyps to delineate
>   specific immunophenotypes by flow cytometry and determine in vitro EO
>   survival in relation to asthmatic status. RESULTS: The CRSwNP in
>   patients with asthma was characterized by eosinophilia and a high
>   level of interleukin (IL)-5 in nasal secretions. Although EOs
>   exhibited activation profiles after mucosal migration, there was
>   relative down-expression of IL-5 receptor-? (IL-5R?) on nasal EOs in
>   patients with asthma. The EO culture with IL-5 and IL-9 showed an
>   antiapoptotic effect in patients with asthma through IL-5R?
>   modulation. CONCLUSION: Mucosal eosinophilia seems to be induced by EO
>   nasal trapping through modulation of adhesion receptors. In patients
>   with asthma, EO involvement is enhanced by the antiapoptotic
>   synergistic action of T-helper cell type 2 cytokines on IL-5R?
>   expression. This study shows for the first time that IL-9 is involved
>   in EO homeostasis in CRSwNP and could explain the low benefit of
>   anti-IL-5 therapy for some patients with asthma and nasal polyposis.
>
> **cytokineTerms:**    t cell replacing factortype ii interferonc7chemokineinterleukin 17 precursorleukocyte
>   mediatorinterleukinst cell replacing factort cell replacing factoril9
>   proteininterferon alpha-5cytokinesil9 protein
>
> **cancerTerms:**  butnotnot necessarilyalthough
>
> ***version*:**    1522116540216901632
>
> **score:**    1.0

Here is some of the code (please forgive the mess. I have included changes for Solr ver. 5):
**UpdateScript**

```
/***************************UpdateScript*********************************/

    function getAnalyzerResult(analyzer, fieldName, fieldValue) {
      var result = [];
      var token_stream = analyzer.tokenStream(fieldName, new java.io.StringReader(fieldValue));//null value?
      var term_att = token_stream.getAttribute(Packages.org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute.class);
      token_stream.reset();
      while (token_stream.incrementToken()) {
        result.push(term_att.toString());
      }
      token_stream.end();
      token_stream.close();
      return result;
    }
    function processAdd(cmd) {
      doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
      id = doc.getFieldValue("id");
      logger.warn("update-script#processAdd: id=" + id);

      var content = doc.getFieldValue("content"); // Comes from /update/extract
      //facetList contains the actual facet terms
      //facetAnalyzerName contains the Analyzer name for the term vector list names. (i.e the field type)
      var facetList = ["cytokineTerms", "cancerTerms"];
      var facetAnalyzerName = ["key_phrases", "ColonCancer"];
      /*
        Loop through all of the facets, and get the analyzer and the name for the field
        Then add the terms to the document
      */
      for(var i = 0; i < facetList.length; i++){
        var analyzer = req.getCore().getLatestSchema().getFieldTypeByName(facetAnalyzerName[i]).getIndexAnalyzer();
        var terms = getAnalyzerResult(analyzer, null, content);
        for(var index = 0; index < terms.length; index++){
          doc.addField(facetList[i], terms[index]);  
        }
      }  
    }
    // The functions below must be defined, but there's rarely a need to implement
    // anything in these.
    function processDelete(cmd) {
      // no-op
    }
    function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
      // no-op
    }
    function processCommit(cmd) {
      // no-op
    }
    function processRollback(cmd) {
      // no-op
    }
    function finish() {
      // no-op
    }
    /***************************UpdateScript*********************************/
```

**updateRequestProcessorChain**

```
/****************updateRequestProcessorChain ***********************/
    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="script" default="true">
      <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <str name="script">update-script.js</str>
        <lst name="params">
          <str name="config_param">example config parameter</str>
        </lst>
      </processor>
      <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
      <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    </updateRequestProcessorChain>
/****************updateRequestProcessorChain ***********************/
```

**Upload using post**

```
 java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/Cytokine/update -Dauto -Dparams=update.chain=script -jar bin/post.jar C:/Users/Kevin/Downloads/pubmed_result.json
```

Sources:

1. http://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/06/27/poor-mans-entity-extraction-with-solr/
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXSK2RvVJsk
3. https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor
   4.https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_0_0/changes/Changes.html#v5.0.0.upgrading_from_solr_4.x
4. https://gist.github.com/erikhatcher/50e653c1c09abb68e068

Archive:
https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201512.mbox/%3CCAH57+p4FK=Ta84dEpUR4p0xWQ2YWkOWPpj566ZZzhdjW9F_ZJg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, something goes wrong between your synonyms and your KeepWord list. In the Admin UI, there is Analyse screen, where you can put your original text and your search string and see both go through the analysis using the chosen field (ColonCancerField for you). The matches would be highlighted.

That's for the search. For the facets, using ColonCancerField should have worked for the facets, try it without any search (q=*:*).

The KeywordTokenizer does not split the text at all, so you should get the whole field as a facet.

Also, the copyText directives do NOT layer. So you cannot copy field1 to field2 and then field2 to field3. You need to copy field1 to both field2 and field3. That's probably part of your issue here.

Comment: ok so they don't layer, bummer. Okay, so I did try the analyze and found that both terms show up, so the final filter is KeepWordFilterFactory and I get for the terms not | not necessarily. For example I have a few documents, one says "not necessarily" and another that says "not really" and when I search ColonCancer:"not necessarily" I get both documents.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that the keepwords and the synonyms can conflict, if they do then it will give very strange results. For example it states that there are documents, and when selected there are none.